# ignite-indexing and H2 version

Tags: h2, ignite

When I use the spatial index module in ignite1.6.0 , I found it depends 1.3.175 version of the H2, but I need to use the 1.4.X h2 version.

```html
 <dependency>
      <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
      <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.175</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

This method org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing # start will call org.h2.constant.SysProperties and org.h2.util.Utils, in front of the class in the 1.3.176 version of the above have been It does not exist, the latter class is missing serializer variables.

```html
 if (SysProperties.serializeJavaObject) {
            U.warn(log, "Serialization of Java objects in H2 was enabled.");

            SysProperties.serializeJavaObject = false;
        }

        if (Utils.serializer != null)
            U.warn(log, "Custom H2 serialization is already configured, will override.");

        Utils.serializer = h2Serializer();
```

Is there any way to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Ignite depends on H2 1.3.175 and you can't use any other version. If you already have some code that depends on 1.4, you should isolate Ignite-related code in a separate module in your project. This way different versions of H2 will coextist.